# Connect to Milo Server

Tags: server, opc-ua, milo

I created a small Milo Server but can't connect to it with the Prosys OPC UA Client - other clients work fine. I guess its similar to this problem: [Configuration OPC UA Server (Milo)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38830195/configuration-opc-ua-server-milo) but i don't understand which address to use for the setBindAddresses() as Kevin suggested in the answer.

here is my log for starting the server and trying to connect with the prosys client:

```
15:51:12.230 [main] INFO  Main - security temp dir: C:\Users\lukr\AppData\Local\Temp\security
15:51:12.246 [main] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.c.a.DefaultCertificateValidator - Synchronizing trusted certificates...
15:51:12.246 [main] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.c.a.DefaultCertificateValidator - trustedCertificates.size()=0, authorityCertificates.size()=0
15:51:12.261 [main] INFO  o.e.milo.opcua.stack.core.Stack - Successfully removed cryptography restrictions.
15:51:12.464 [main] DEBUG i.n.u.i.l.InternalLoggerFactory - Using SLF4J as the default logging framework
15:51:12.464 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.Buffer.address: available
15:51:12.464 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - sun.misc.Unsafe.theUnsafe: available
15:51:12.464 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - sun.misc.Unsafe.copyMemory: available
15:51:12.464 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.Bits.unaligned: true
15:51:12.464 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - Platform: Windows
15:51:12.464 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - Java version: 8
15:51:12.464 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.noUnsafe: false
15:51:12.464 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - sun.misc.Unsafe: available
15:51:12.464 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.noJavassist: false
15:51:12.511 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - Javassist: available
15:51:12.511 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.tmpdir: C:\Users\lukr\AppData\Local\Temp (java.io.tmpdir)
15:51:12.511 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.bitMode: 64 (sun.arch.data.model)
15:51:12.511 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.noPreferDirect: false
15:51:12.511 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector - -Dio.netty.leakDetection.level: simple
15:51:12.511 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector - -Dio.netty.leakDetection.maxRecords: 4
15:51:12.854 [main] INFO  o.e.m.o.s.s.n.OpcUaNamespace - Loaded nodes in 309ms.
15:51:12.886 [main] INFO  o.e.m.o.sdk.server.NamespaceManager - added namespace index=0, uri=http://opcfoundation.org/UA/
15:51:12.886 [main] INFO  o.e.m.o.sdk.server.NamespaceManager - registered and added namespace index=1, uri=urn:milo:sag:example
15:51:12.933 [main] INFO  o.e.m.opcua.sdk.server.OpcUaServer - Binding endpoint opc.tcp://PCLUKR02:12686/example to 0.0.0.0 [None/None]
15:51:12.933 [main] INFO  o.e.m.opcua.sdk.server.OpcUaServer - Binding endpoint opc.tcp://PCLUKR02:12686/example to 0.0.0.0 [Basic128Rsa15/SignAndEncrypt]
15:51:12.933 [main] INFO  o.e.m.opcua.sdk.server.OpcUaServer - Binding endpoint opc.tcp://PCLUKR02:12686/example to 0.0.0.0 [Basic256/SignAndEncrypt]
15:51:12.933 [main] INFO  o.e.m.opcua.sdk.server.OpcUaServer - Binding endpoint opc.tcp://PCLUKR02:12686/example to 0.0.0.0 [Basic256Sha256/SignAndEncrypt]
15:51:12.933 [main] INFO  o.e.m.opcua.sdk.server.OpcUaServer - Binding endpoint opc.tcp://PCLUKR02.eur.ad.sag:12686/example to 0.0.0.0 [None/None]
15:51:12.933 [main] INFO  o.e.m.opcua.sdk.server.OpcUaServer - Binding endpoint opc.tcp://PCLUKR02.eur.ad.sag:12686/example to 0.0.0.0 [Basic128Rsa15/SignAndEncrypt]
15:51:12.933 [main] INFO  o.e.m.opcua.sdk.server.OpcUaServer - Binding endpoint opc.tcp://PCLUKR02.eur.ad.sag:12686/example to 0.0.0.0 [Basic256/SignAndEncrypt]
15:51:12.933 [main] INFO  o.e.m.opcua.sdk.server.OpcUaServer - Binding endpoint opc.tcp://PCLUKR02.eur.ad.sag:12686/example to 0.0.0.0 [Basic256Sha256/SignAndEncrypt]
15:51:12.933 [main] INFO  o.e.m.opcua.sdk.server.OpcUaServer - Binding endpoint opc.tcp://169.254.216.48:12686/example to 0.0.0.0 [None/None]
15:51:12.933 [main] INFO  o.e.m.opcua.sdk.server.OpcUaServer - Binding endpoint opc.tcp://169.254.216.48:12686/example to 0.0.0.0 [Basic128Rsa15/SignAndEncrypt]
15:51:12.933 [main] INFO  o.e.m.opcua.sdk.server.OpcUaServer - Binding endpoint opc.tcp://169.254.216.48:12686/example to 0.0.0.0 [Basic256/SignAndEncrypt]
15:51:12.933 [main] INFO  o.e.m.opcua.sdk.server.OpcUaServer - Binding endpoint opc.tcp://169.254.216.48:12686/example to 0.0.0.0 [Basic256Sha256/SignAndEncrypt]
15:51:12.933 [main] INFO  o.e.m.opcua.sdk.server.OpcUaServer - Binding endpoint opc.tcp://127.0.0.1:12686/example to 0.0.0.0 [None/None]
15:51:12.933 [main] INFO  o.e.m.opcua.sdk.server.OpcUaServer - Binding endpoint opc.tcp://127.0.0.1:12686/example to 0.0.0.0 [Basic128Rsa15/SignAndEncrypt]
15:51:12.933 [main] INFO  o.e.m.opcua.sdk.server.OpcUaServer - Binding endpoint opc.tcp://127.0.0.1:12686/example to 0.0.0.0 [Basic256/SignAndEncrypt]
15:51:12.933 [main] INFO  o.e.m.opcua.sdk.server.OpcUaServer - Binding endpoint opc.tcp://127.0.0.1:12686/example to 0.0.0.0 [Basic256Sha256/SignAndEncrypt]
15:51:12.933 [main] INFO  o.e.m.opcua.sdk.server.OpcUaServer - Binding endpoint opc.tcp://10.22.26.45:12686/example to 0.0.0.0 [None/None]
15:51:12.933 [main] INFO  o.e.m.opcua.sdk.server.OpcUaServer - Binding endpoint opc.tcp://10.22.26.45:12686/example to 0.0.0.0 [Basic128Rsa15/SignAndEncrypt]
15:51:12.933 [main] INFO  o.e.m.opcua.sdk.server.OpcUaServer - Binding endpoint opc.tcp://10.22.26.45:12686/example to 0.0.0.0 [Basic256/SignAndEncrypt]
15:51:12.933 [main] INFO  o.e.m.opcua.sdk.server.OpcUaServer - Binding endpoint opc.tcp://10.22.26.45:12686/example to 0.0.0.0 [Basic256Sha256/SignAndEncrypt]
15:51:12.949 [main] INFO  o.e.m.opcua.sdk.server.OpcUaServer - eclipse milo opc-ua stack version: 0.1.5
15:51:12.949 [main] INFO  o.e.m.opcua.sdk.server.OpcUaServer - eclipse milo opc-ua sdk version: 0.1.5
15:51:13.011 [main] INFO  o.e.m.o.sdk.server.NamespaceManager - registered and added namespace index=2, uri=urn:eclipse:milo:hello-world
15:51:13.027 [main] DEBUG i.n.c.MultithreadEventLoopGroup - -Dio.netty.eventLoopThreads: 16
15:51:13.027 [main] DEBUG io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop - -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization: false
15:51:13.027 [main] DEBUG io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop - -Dio.netty.selectorAutoRebuildThreshold: 512
15:51:13.058 [main] DEBUG i.n.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.numHeapArenas: 16
15:51:13.058 [main] DEBUG i.n.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas: 16
15:51:13.058 [main] DEBUG i.n.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.pageSize: 8192
15:51:13.058 [main] DEBUG i.n.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.maxOrder: 11
15:51:13.058 [main] DEBUG i.n.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.chunkSize: 16777216
15:51:13.058 [main] DEBUG i.n.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.tinyCacheSize: 512
15:51:13.058 [main] DEBUG i.n.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.smallCacheSize: 256
15:51:13.058 [main] DEBUG i.n.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.normalCacheSize: 64
15:51:13.058 [main] DEBUG i.n.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.maxCachedBufferCapacity: 32768
15:51:13.058 [main] DEBUG i.n.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.cacheTrimInterval: 8192
15:51:13.073 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.ThreadLocalRandom - -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier: 0x73803014053032d5 (took 1 ms)
15:51:13.073 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil - -Dio.netty.allocator.type: unpooled
15:51:13.073 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil - -Dio.netty.threadLocalDirectBufferSize: 65536
15:51:13.073 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil - -Dio.netty.maxThreadLocalCharBufferSize: 16384
15:51:13.120 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.NetUtil - Loopback interface: lo (Software Loopback Interface 1, 127.0.0.1)
15:51:13.120 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.NetUtil - \proc\sys\net\core\somaxconn: 200 (non-existent)
15:51:13.120 [ua-netty-event-loop-0] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.t.SocketServers$SocketServer - [id: 0x743a292f] REGISTERED
15:51:13.120 [ua-netty-event-loop-0] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.t.SocketServers$SocketServer - [id: 0x743a292f] BIND(/0.0.0.0:12686)
15:51:13.120 [ua-netty-event-loop-0] INFO  o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - opc.tcp://PCLUKR02:12686/example bound to 0.0.0.0:12686 [None/None]
15:51:13.120 [ua-netty-event-loop-0] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.t.SocketServers$SocketServer - [id: 0x743a292f, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:12686] ACTIVE
15:51:13.120 [main] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.t.SocketServers$SocketServer - Added server at path: "/example"
15:51:13.120 [main] INFO  o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - opc.tcp://PCLUKR02:12686/example bound to 0.0.0.0:12686 [Basic128Rsa15/SignAndEncrypt]
15:51:13.120 [main] INFO  o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - opc.tcp://PCLUKR02:12686/example bound to 0.0.0.0:12686 [Basic256/SignAndEncrypt]
15:51:13.120 [main] INFO  o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - opc.tcp://PCLUKR02:12686/example bound to 0.0.0.0:12686 [Basic256Sha256/SignAndEncrypt]
15:51:13.120 [main] INFO  o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - opc.tcp://PCLUKR02.eur.ad.sag:12686/example bound to 0.0.0.0:12686 [None/None]
15:51:13.120 [main] INFO  o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - opc.tcp://PCLUKR02.eur.ad.sag:12686/example bound to 0.0.0.0:12686 [Basic128Rsa15/SignAndEncrypt]
15:51:13.120 [main] INFO  o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - opc.tcp://PCLUKR02.eur.ad.sag:12686/example bound to 0.0.0.0:12686 [Basic256/SignAndEncrypt]
15:51:13.120 [main] INFO  o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - opc.tcp://PCLUKR02.eur.ad.sag:12686/example bound to 0.0.0.0:12686 [Basic256Sha256/SignAndEncrypt]
15:51:13.120 [main] INFO  o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - opc.tcp://169.254.216.48:12686/example bound to 0.0.0.0:12686 [None/None]
15:51:13.120 [main] INFO  o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - opc.tcp://169.254.216.48:12686/example bound to 0.0.0.0:12686 [Basic128Rsa15/SignAndEncrypt]
15:51:13.120 [main] INFO  o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - opc.tcp://169.254.216.48:12686/example bound to 0.0.0.0:12686 [Basic256/SignAndEncrypt]
15:51:13.120 [main] INFO  o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - opc.tcp://169.254.216.48:12686/example bound to 0.0.0.0:12686 [Basic256Sha256/SignAndEncrypt]
15:51:13.136 [main] INFO  o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - opc.tcp://127.0.0.1:12686/example bound to 0.0.0.0:12686 [None/None]
15:51:13.136 [main] INFO  o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - opc.tcp://127.0.0.1:12686/example bound to 0.0.0.0:12686 [Basic128Rsa15/SignAndEncrypt]
15:51:13.136 [main] INFO  o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - opc.tcp://127.0.0.1:12686/example bound to 0.0.0.0:12686 [Basic256/SignAndEncrypt]
15:51:13.136 [main] INFO  o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - opc.tcp://127.0.0.1:12686/example bound to 0.0.0.0:12686 [Basic256Sha256/SignAndEncrypt]
15:51:13.136 [main] INFO  o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - opc.tcp://10.22.26.45:12686/example bound to 0.0.0.0:12686 [None/None]
15:51:13.136 [main] INFO  o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - opc.tcp://10.22.26.45:12686/example bound to 0.0.0.0:12686 [Basic128Rsa15/SignAndEncrypt]
15:51:13.136 [main] INFO  o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - opc.tcp://10.22.26.45:12686/example bound to 0.0.0.0:12686 [Basic256/SignAndEncrypt]
15:51:13.136 [main] INFO  o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - opc.tcp://10.22.26.45:12686/example bound to 0.0.0.0:12686 [Basic256Sha256/SignAndEncrypt]
15:51:15.866 [ua-netty-event-loop-0] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.t.SocketServers$SocketServer - [id: 0x743a292f, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:12686] RECEIVED: [id: 0xb8884593, L:/127.0.0.1:12686 - R:/127.0.0.1:58005]
15:51:15.913 [ua-netty-event-loop-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.Recycler - -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacity.default: 262144
15:51:15.913 [ua-netty-event-loop-1] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf - -Dio.netty.buffer.bytebuf.checkAccessible: true
15:51:15.929 [ua-netty-event-loop-1] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.h.UaTcpServerHelloHandler - [remote=/127.0.0.1:58005] Received Hello message.
15:51:16.116 [ua-netty-event-loop-1] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.h.UaTcpServerHelloHandler - [remote=/127.0.0.1:58005] Removed HelloHandler, added AsymmetricHandler.
15:51:16.116 [ua-netty-event-loop-1] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.h.UaTcpServerHelloHandler - [remote=/127.0.0.1:58005] Sent Acknowledge message.
15:51:16.132 [ua-shared-pool-0] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.h.UaTcpServerAsymmetricHandler - Received OpenSecureChannelRequest (Issue, id=0).
15:51:16.132 [ua-shared-pool-1] DEBUG i.n.u.i.JavassistTypeParameterMatcherGenerator - Generated: io.netty.util.internal.__matchers__.org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.application.services.ServiceResponseMatcher
15:51:16.132 [ua-shared-pool-1] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.h.UaTcpServerAsymmetricHandler - Sent OpenSecureChannelResponse.
15:51:16.147 [ua-shared-pool-0] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - requestedHost=localhost, discoveryHost=127.0.0.1
15:51:16.147 [ua-shared-pool-0] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - requestedHost=localhost, discoveryHost=10.22.26.45
15:51:16.147 [ua-shared-pool-0] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - requestedHost=localhost, discoveryHost=169.254.216.48
15:51:16.147 [ua-shared-pool-0] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - requestedHost=localhost, discoveryHost=PCLUKR02
15:51:16.147 [ua-shared-pool-0] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - requestedHost=localhost, discoveryHost=PCLUKR02.eur.ad.sag
15:51:16.147 [ua-shared-pool-0] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - requestedHostAddress=localhost, discoveryHostAddress=127.0.0.1
15:51:16.147 [ua-shared-pool-0] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - requestedHostAddress=localhost, discoveryHostAddress=10.22.26.45
15:51:16.147 [ua-shared-pool-0] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - requestedHostAddress=localhost, discoveryHostAddress=169.254.216.48
15:51:16.147 [ua-shared-pool-0] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - requestedHostAddress=localhost, discoveryHostAddress=PCLUKR02
15:51:16.147 [ua-shared-pool-0] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - requestedHostAddress=localhost, discoveryHostAddress=PCLUKR02.eur.ad.sag
15:51:16.147 [ua-shared-pool-0] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - Matching discovery URLs: [opc.tcp://127.0.0.1:12686/example]
15:51:16.147 [ua-netty-event-loop-1] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.h.UaTcpServerAsymmetricHandler - Received CloseSecureChannelRequest
15:51:16.147 [ua-netty-event-loop-1] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - Removed secure channel id=1
15:51:16.147 [ua-netty-event-loop-1] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - Closing secure channel id=1, bound channel: [id: 0xb8884593, L:/127.0.0.1:12686 - R:/127.0.0.1:58005]
15:51:16.194 [ua-netty-event-loop-0] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.t.SocketServers$SocketServer - [id: 0x743a292f, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:12686] RECEIVED: [id: 0xf22b577a, L:/127.0.0.1:12686 - R:/127.0.0.1:58006]
15:51:16.194 [ua-netty-event-loop-2] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.h.UaTcpServerHelloHandler - [remote=/127.0.0.1:58006] Received Hello message.
15:51:16.194 [ua-netty-event-loop-2] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.h.UaTcpServerHelloHandler - [remote=/127.0.0.1:58006] Removed HelloHandler, added AsymmetricHandler.
15:51:16.194 [ua-netty-event-loop-2] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.h.UaTcpServerHelloHandler - [remote=/127.0.0.1:58006] Sent Acknowledge message.
15:51:16.194 [ua-shared-pool-0] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.h.UaTcpServerAsymmetricHandler - Received OpenSecureChannelRequest (Issue, id=0).
15:51:16.194 [ua-shared-pool-1] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.h.UaTcpServerAsymmetricHandler - Sent OpenSecureChannelResponse.
15:51:16.194 [ua-shared-pool-0] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - requestedHost=localhost, discoveryHost=127.0.0.1
15:51:16.194 [ua-shared-pool-0] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - requestedHost=localhost, discoveryHost=10.22.26.45
15:51:16.194 [ua-shared-pool-0] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - requestedHost=localhost, discoveryHost=169.254.216.48
15:51:16.194 [ua-shared-pool-0] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - requestedHost=localhost, discoveryHost=PCLUKR02
15:51:16.194 [ua-shared-pool-0] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - requestedHost=localhost, discoveryHost=PCLUKR02.eur.ad.sag
15:51:16.194 [ua-shared-pool-0] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - requestedHostAddress=localhost, discoveryHostAddress=127.0.0.1
15:51:16.194 [ua-shared-pool-0] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - requestedHostAddress=localhost, discoveryHostAddress=10.22.26.45
15:51:16.194 [ua-shared-pool-0] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - requestedHostAddress=localhost, discoveryHostAddress=169.254.216.48
15:51:16.194 [ua-shared-pool-0] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - requestedHostAddress=localhost, discoveryHostAddress=PCLUKR02
15:51:16.194 [ua-shared-pool-0] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - requestedHostAddress=localhost, discoveryHostAddress=PCLUKR02.eur.ad.sag
15:51:16.194 [ua-shared-pool-0] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - Matching discovery URLs: [opc.tcp://127.0.0.1:12686/example]
15:51:16.194 [ua-netty-event-loop-2] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.h.UaTcpServerAsymmetricHandler - Received CloseSecureChannelRequest
15:51:16.194 [ua-netty-event-loop-2] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - Removed secure channel id=2
15:51:16.194 [ua-netty-event-loop-2] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.tcp.UaTcpStackServer - Closing secure channel id=2, bound channel: [id: 0xf22b577a, L:/127.0.0.1:12686 - R:/127.0.0.1:58006]
15:51:16.194 [ua-netty-event-loop-0] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.t.SocketServers$SocketServer - [id: 0x743a292f, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:12686] RECEIVED: [id: 0x81faf8a1, L:/127.0.0.1:12686 - R:/127.0.0.1:58007]
15:51:16.210 [ua-netty-event-loop-3] DEBUG o.e.m.o.s.s.h.UaTcpServerHelloHandler - [remote=/127.0.0.1:58007] Received Hello message.
15:51:16.225 [ua-netty-event-loop-3] ERROR o.e.m.o.s.s.h.UaTcpServerHelloHandler - [remote=/127.0.0.1:58007] Exception caught; sent ErrorMessage{error=StatusCode{name=Bad_TcpEndpointUrlInvalid, value=0x80830000, quality=bad}, reason=unrecognized endpoint url: }
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: UaException: status=Bad_TcpEndpointUrlInvalid, message=unrecognized endpoint url: 
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:418)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:245)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:292)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:278)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:962)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:528)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:485)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:399)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:371)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.UaException: unrecognized endpoint url: 
    at org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.server.handlers.UaTcpServerHelloHandler.lambda$onHello$0(UaTcpServerHelloHandler.java:86)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.server.handlers.UaTcpServerHelloHandler.onHello(UaTcpServerHelloHandler.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.server.handlers.UaTcpServerHelloHandler.decode(UaTcpServerHelloHandler.java:68)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:387)
    ... 11 common frames omitted
15:52:16.751 [threadDeathWatcher-2-1] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache - Freed 2 thread-local buffer(s) from thread: ua-shared-pool-1
15:52:16.751 [threadDeathWatcher-2-1] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache - Freed 2 thread-local buffer(s) from thread: ua-shared-pool-0
```

the server config:

`OpcUaServerConfig serverConfig = OpcUaServerConfig.builder()
            .setApplicationUri(uri)
            .setApplicationName(LocalizedText.english(description))
            .setBindPort(port)
            .setBindAddresses(newArrayList("0.0.0.0"))
            .setBuildInfo(
                new BuildInfo(
                    uri,
                    "test",
                    description,
                    OpcUaServer.SDK_VERSION,
                    "v.0.1", DateTime.now()))
            .setCertificateManager(certificateManager)
            .setCertificateValidator(certificateValidator)
            .setIdentityValidator(identityValidator)
            .setProductUri(uri)
            .setServerName(name)
            .setSecurityPolicies(
                EnumSet.of(
                    SecurityPolicy.None,
                    SecurityPolicy.Basic128Rsa15,
                    SecurityPolicy.Basic256,
                    SecurityPolicy.Basic256Sha256))
            .setUserTokenPolicies(
                ImmutableList.of(
                    USER_TOKEN_POLICY_ANONYMOUS,
                    USER_TOKEN_POLICY_USERNAME))
            .build();`

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: what connection url worked in the other clients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a bug in the version of the Prosys client you're using.

The underlying error:

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.UaException: unrecognized endpoint url: 
    at org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.server.handlers.UaTcpServerHelloHandler.lambda$onHello$0(UaTcpServerHelloHandler.java:86) 
    at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290) 
    at org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.server.handlers.UaTcpServerHelloHandler.onHello(UaTcpServerHelloHandler.java:83)
```

The Prosys client is sending an empty string in the endpoint URL field of the Hello message instead of the one used to connect. I've seen this before and I'm certain they've fixed this in some subsequent version of their UA stack already.

Comment: I get this with KepServerEx Opc-UA client driver and Ignition too.

Comment: Ok. Nevermind. I got it to work by including the name of my server at the end of the url. opc.tcp://localhost:12686/demo instead of opc.tcp://localhost:12686/

Comment: @RexNFX yes, the endpoint URL must match and the name of the server is used in the endpoint URL.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar -
Try the discovery uri logged.

It's `opc.tcp://hostname:port/serverName`
Milo exposes another secondary discovery address that you can also try to connect to to get more info but the former is the one to use: `opc.tcp://hostname:port/serverName/discovery`

eg where serverName is from the builder's setServerName line

```
val serverConfig = OpcUaServerConfig.
  builder.
  setApplicationUri(applicationUri).
  setApplicationName(LocalizedText.english("Jason's OPCUA Server)")).
  setBindAddresses(bindAddresses.asJava).
  setEndpointAddresses(endpointAddresses.asJava).
  setBindPort(12000). //FIXME use config
  setBuildInfo(new BuildInfo(applicationUri, "Yo Dawg", "Purple Drank", OpcUaServer.SDK_VERSION, "0.0.0", DateTime.now)).
  setCertificateManager(certificateManager).
  setCertificateValidator(certificateValidator).
  setIdentityValidator(new CompositeValidator(identityValidator, x509IdentityValidator)).
  //      setProductUri("urn:JasonGoodwin:OPCUA:playerserver:" + UUID.randomUUID().toString).
  setProductUri("jason/test1").
  setServerName("example").
  setSecurityPolicies(util.EnumSet.of(SecurityPolicy.None, SecurityPolicy.Basic128Rsa15, SecurityPolicy.Basic256, SecurityPolicy.Basic256Sha256)).
  setUserTokenPolicies(ImmutableList.of(USER_TOKEN_POLICY_ANONYMOUS, USER_TOKEN_POLICY_X509, USER_TOKEN_POLICY_USERNAME)).
  build
```